# `TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(4)/b/n' undefined error in kpfonts-otf when useing \mathversion{bold}

Tags: fonts, warnings, math-fonts, kpfonts

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}
    Some text.\mathversion{bold}$a$
\end{document}
```

[image: kpfonts-otf]

The code compiles fine using without any errors and gives the expected output. But I get a warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(4)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/KpMath-Regular.otf(4)/m/n' instead on input line 
6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I don't understand why. The bold math font `KpMath-Bold.otf` is available, it contains the required glyph, and the pdf output is correct as well.

Comment: the package should probably setup the bold font also in the range command (`\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}[range={cal,bfcal},RawFeature=+ss01,BoldFont=KpMath-Bold.otf]`). Notify the author.

Comment: According to the documentation (`texdoc kpfonts-otf` p.11) the bold version, if used, should be defined in the preamble: `\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]`, then the warning disappears. I could follow Ulrike's suggestion, but what about \version{sans} etc.?

Comment: @DanielFlipo Thanks. I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that using `\mathversion{xyz}` requires an appropriate definition in the preamble (that's the way it is described in the `unicode-math` documentation).

Adding `\setmathfont{KpMath-Bold.otf}[version=bold]` to the preamble suppresses the warning.

Nevertheless, Ulrike is right…

In `kpfonts-otf.sty`, I have recently added `BoldFont=KpMath-Bold.otf` to the main definition of `KpMath-Regular`, it was meant for the `\boldmath` command (not for `\mathversion{bold}`).  I naïvely thought that the variant defined for `range={cal,bfcal}` would inherit of it automatically but obviously it doesn't. I will fix it for the next version ---which will probably not released before a few weeks unless another more severe bug shows up.  The best way is probably to add `.fontspec` files defining the BoldFont for `KpMath-Regular`, `KpMath-Light` and `KpMath-Sans`, so that it also helps users who do not load the `kpfonts-otf` style file.